# Jquery conflict in Wordpress after move into another hosting

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

i was looking for some solution it but i didnt find anything.
I think its jquery conflict. I have installed smart-slider, and after move my Wordpress into another hosting its just stopped working. My browser shows me: "undefined its not a function", and my code (generated by plugin ofc):

```
<script>
    njQuery(document).ready(function () {
        njQuery('#nextend-smart-slider-1').smartslider({parameters});
    });
</script>
```

I was trying to change it into $.('#next.. or jQuery('#next, but it still broke.
Any ideas?

Comment: And why are you using `njQuery` and not `jQuery`, there should be no need to define your own jQuery variable in Wordpress ?

Comment: It's generated by smart-slider plugin, and before move my files it was working. But anyway i was trying use jQuery also by adding this code into <head>, but still no results.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the code to be a simple jQuery. And not the njQuery.

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('#nextend-smart-slider-1').smartslider({parameters});
    });
</script>
```

Otherwise it won't work. Or else, just make sure that the server has a variable or a script file to handle the `njQuery` too.

Comment: For example, fancybox uses njQuery and it's working, so I don't know where problem is.

Comment: Umm ok, can I get the wordpress blog url? Pleaes?

Comment: I've send you by Facebook, if you want to help (if not just ignore), thanks.